# matplotlib storing and removing artist

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have encountered a strange issue with matplotlib artists.

Disclaimer: Unfortunately I only ever used matplotlib in jupyter notebooks and in a tkinter GUI (the latter is where I found this) so I do not know how to write simple code that will replicate the issue. However I do not think sample is code is absolutely needed in this case.

Now the issue:

In the interest of speeding up plotting in a GUI I do not plot everything anew whenever elements of the plot change but rather make use of methods like `set_ydata` and `canvas.draw`. Sometimes it is also necessary to remove lines altogether which can be accomplished with `artist.remove`. Here is the problem: When I have one or several artist(s) stored in a list I can successfully remove them from the plot by iterating over the list and calling `remove`. If however I store the reference directly (as an attribute of the class that is managing plots), calling `remove` does not do anything.

As sketch of the code suppose we have

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
```

the first case is generated by something like

```
artist_list = list()
for x in range(5):
    line = ax.axhline(x)
    artist_list.append(line)
```

and can be removed by

```
for line in artist_list:
    line.remove()
artist_list = list()
```

(the last is needed for this to work).

whereas the second would be

```
line = ax.axhline(1)
line.remove()
```

which does not remove the line from the plot (even if `del line` or `line = None` are added).

It seems that storing the artist in a list and then assigning that variable to a new empty list is somehow a more complete removal than reassigning the variable that stores the artist directly or even deleting it. Does somebody know what is going here? How could a line be removed if it is simply stored as `line` rather than in a list?

Answer (score 4):

As can be seen from the below piece of code, removing a line is pretty easy. Indeed, you just call `.remove()` on the object in question and redraw the canvas.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set(title="Click to remove line", xlim=(0,2))

line=ax.axvline(1)

def remove_line(event):
    line.remove()
    fig.canvas.draw()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect("button_press_event", remove_line)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but as I tried to explain this does not actually work (at least in the context I described).

Comment: As I'm showing in this answer, it *does* work. Maybe your code is incomplete? If you can provide me with a single piece of runnable code where this problem occurs I can help you find out about the problem.